# Lat long api does'not work

Tags: php, google-maps

After a long search and implementation i am here to need your help..I am using google api to calculate lat long; for this in code i call the api like below mentioned

```
$jsondata=file_get_contents(@'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="75300+Karachi+PK"&sensor=false&#8217;');
```

but it return me null array data; but if same url of api if i type on browser like `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%2275300+Karachi+PK%22&sensor=false&#8217` then it shows me the data in array

what i get mostly in searches that the error is because more than 2500 requests, however i am not sending a 2500 requests obviously.

really appreciate any help; please guide id there is any mistake in my code

Comment: instead of "file_get_contents" use "CURL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsondata=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="75300+Karachi+PK"&sensor=false&#8217;');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `http://` in url when you call `file_get_contents`.

p.s. and remove that `@` in function call.